# Remap 1 key to 3 keys in Karabiner Elements

Tags: macos, karabiner

I'd like to remap the key f, to 1, 2, f.
Now, whenever I press the key f, the system immediately types 1, 2, and f.
Is there a way to do that in Karabiner elements?

Comment: What do you mean? This quessays theat Now it does whjat you want

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, add

```
{
"description": "key f to f12 ",
"manipulators": [
                {
      "from": { "key_code": "f" },
      "to": [
              { "key_code": "1" },
              { "key_code": "2" },
              { "key_code": "f",
                "repeat": false }
            ],
      "type": "basic"
                }
                ]
},
```

to your Karabiner.json file (without "repeat" => 12ffffffff… ).

Remember that this re-map will work in *EVERY* app if you don't constrict it via "bundle_identifiers" to one (or several ones) !